# Focal length vs Principal point

Tags: remote-sensing, imagery, photogrammetry, altitude

I have set of areal imagery.

One of a parameters I get with images is camera's `Principal Distance` , what I'm looking for is `Focal length`, but I don't have `Focal length` at the moment

I tried to substitute between two to create DEM with one of the commercial software, as a result I'm getting wrong `Altitude`.

Maybe there is some calculation that can be used to get `Focal length` from `Principal Distance` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting wrong altitude values not because the focal distance. The altitudes computations depends of some factors:

- Numbers of photos for intersection calculus: If you have few photos for each point, errors in the intersection will be absorbed in Z coordinate.
- Number and distribution of GCP's: The ground control points must to be correctly distributed along the strip or block of photos, if not erros can be propagated in the computations.
- Reference System: Are you using a geodetic tridimentional reference system? When you say "wrong altitudes" what are you comparing to say that's wrong?

In this document (pages: 40 to 43) you can find forms of improve your computation avoiding the points I have cited above: http://geography.middlebury.edu/data/gg1002/Handouts/LPS_PM.pdf